# Reshape a list of tuples into a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

**Python 3.7**

I have an matlab/octave .dat file which has the following structure (35,45,48) = 75600 points, since I have no idea on how to handle that format in python I decided to import the data as a .txt file from octave and the manipulate from there.

the following points in the data set looks like this:

```
(-14.46997737884521, 4.298966407775879)
```

This .txt file from octave gives me an array of (75600 x 1), so this is my approach:

I am not sure if the reshape i am making gives me the properly array I need which should be exactly the same as in matlab/octave.

- read the file with python and receive a list as string
- modify it and convert it into a list of 75600 tuples
- then I reshape the array to get the exactly 3D array as in octave

Code:

```
import numpy as np

file = 'data1.txt'
myarray = []
my_tuple_list = []

with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

def createGenerator():
    for i in range(5,len(content)-2):
        yield content[i]

my_generator = createGenerator()

for a in my_generator:
    first_part, second_part = a.split(",")
    num_first_part = first_part.replace("(",'')
    num_second_part = second_part.replace(")",'')
    newtuple = (float(num_first_part),float(num_second_part))
    my_tuple_list.append(newtuple)

arr = np.empty(len(my_tuple_list), dtype='O')
arr[:] = my_tuple_list
new_array = arr.reshape((45,35,48))
```

The result should be an array of (45,35,48) and the elements are inside the array are tuples.

Comment: Can you give a verbatim excerpt of what is in your txt file?

Comment: Generally, you don't really want to be fiddling with the format yourself. I very highly recommend you to create a mock matrix in matlab and observe how it saves the arrays. Say, try a (1, 3, 1) matrix, and then try a (3, 1, 1) matrix. The two need to be fundamentally different, or you can never be sure about the shape of original matrix when you flatten it and read in python.

Comment: tl;dr fix this problem higher up. you need to control/direct how 1. matlab saves it. and 2. how python can directly read it in the correct format.

Comment: You can use [`scipy.io.loadmat()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html#scipy.io.loadmat) to load Matlab `.mat` files.